# Selenium Driver - Webscraping

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using the Selenium Module to try and webscrape but when I print out the element, it seems that it returns a location the data is stored on the Selenium Server?  I'm not exactly sure how this works.  Anyway, here's my code.  I'm very confused.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://caribeexpress.com.do/')  #get method

elem2 = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.plan:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(2)')

print(elem2)

elems3 = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('value')

print(elems3)

elem4 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content-wrapper"]/div[2]/div[3]/div/span[2]')

print(elem4)
```

For some reason, what displays in my Python IDE doesn't display here, I included it in my gist.

https://gist.github.com/jtom343

Comment: What are you expecting it to return? It's going to return object data if you print an object. You could try changing your print to be: `print(elem2.text)' to return the text contained within an element; but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for either?

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to extract the **text** between span tags.

Replace this to :

```
print(elem2)
```

TO:

```
print(elem2.text.strip())
```

and this : `print(elem4)`

To:

```
print(elem4.text.strip())
```